# Rails add unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

This can be beginner thing, but I'm not sure how to deal with it. I want like to add unique constraint to column `username` in existing table psql

the migration create table :

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :requests do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :username
      t.string :address
      t.timestamps null: true
    end
    add_index :requests, :user_id
  end
end
```

So I added validation uniqueness in model

```
class Request < ModelBase
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :username, uniqueness: true
  ...
```

How can I add uniqueness to one column in the database via rails migration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At database level, the way you ensure uniqueness is via indexes. In a migration, create a new unique index for the column.

```
add_index :table_name, :column_name, :unique => true

Or:

rails g migration add_index_to_column_name :column_name, :unique => true
```

Please note that the creation will fail if you have duplicates in the current database. In that case, first go to the CLI and remove the duplicates, then run the migration.

Comment: Your `rails g` statement creates two files and neither of them hold the desired migration. I think you're mixing and matching syntaxes?

Answer (score 2):

To get Ritesh Ranjan's solution using the rails migration generator, try:

```sh
rails g migration add_index_to_table_name column_name:uniq
```

At least in Rails 5.2, this will produce:

```rb
class AddIndexToTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :table_name, :field_name, :string
    add_index :table_name, :field_name, unique: true
  end
end
```

You then just have to remove the `add_column` statement from the migration.

Answer (score 1):

```
def change
  remove_column :requests, :user_id
  change_column :requests, :username, :string, unique: true
  add_reference :requests, :user, index: true
end
```

Comment: `belongs_to :user` this will not validate presence true untill unless user_id does't behave as foreign key.

Comment: Yep. I changed the answer

Comment: yep you got it. but seems it doesn't require to create new migration as user_id already exist in request model. so here just need to drop that migration and create new migration.

Answer (score 1):

if you want username to be unique, I suggest you to use validation in your app/models/user.rb:

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  validates :username, presence:true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

end
```